# Website background image doesn't cover

Tags: javascript, css, background-image

I want to load a random background image using javascript each time a website loads. The background is supposed to cover the full screen. My two backgrounds are not the same , one is like a square image and the other is a shorter and wider one. I want to be able to fill the whole screen , no matter which is selected. 
I've tried to apply the background-cover property to css but it seems to fail. The short background doesn't stretches no matter what.

Update
It now works

```
html{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

body{
    margin : 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-height:100%;
    font-size: 17px;    
}

function loadRandomBackground() {
    var backgroundNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 1);
    document.body.style.background = "url('img/bg" + backgroundNumber +  ".jpg')";
    document.body.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
    document.body.style.backgroundPosition = "center";
    document.body.style.backgroundSize = "cover";
}
```

Comment: css code please but my guess is you haven't made the body be 100% height of the viewport

Comment: I've managed to get it going.

Answer (score 3):

you can set the body CSS like this. There is no need to change it with JS.

```
body{
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```